# python & selenium - aguardar download terminar para fechar o navegador

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

De qual maneira consigo somente fechar a pagina do `webdriver` quando meu download terminar. Time Sleep não me ajudou muito pois os tempos variam muito.

segue meu código:

```
ExportCSV = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div[2]/div/a')))
ExportCSV.click()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Guilherme, muito obrigado, achei um código recentemente e esqueci de compartilhar aqui com vocês.

```
def every_downloads_chrome(driver):
if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
    driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
return driver.execute_script("""
    var items = downloads.Manager.get().items_;
    if (items.every(e => e.state === "COMPLETE"))
        return items.map(e => e.fileUrl || e.file_url);
    """)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 1).until(every_downloads_chrome)
```

Ele vai para a pagina de download e verifica se foi concluido.

Comment: Isso é muito interessante, uma solução simples.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possivel fazer isto com [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) (até aonde eu sei e pesquisei), o que você pode fazer é pegar a URL do link e fazer o download via Python diretamente, por exemplo:

### Se for Python 2.x

> Não pude testar, não uso python2

```
from os.path import basename
from urllib import urlretrieve

...

ExportCSV = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div[2]/div/a')))

url = ExportCSV.get_attribute('href')

# Remove querystring (se houver)
arquivo = url[:url.find('?', 0)]

#remove espaços em branco e barras
arquivo = arquivo.strip().strip('/')

# Pega somente o nome
arquivo = basename(arquivo)

urlretrieve(url, nome)

driver.quit()
```

### Se for Python 3.x

```
from os.path import basename
from urllib import request

...


ExportCSV = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div[2]/div/a')))

url = ExportCSV.get_attribute('href')

# Remove querystring (se houver)
arquivo = url[:url.find('?', 0)]

#remove espaços em branco e barras
arquivo = arquivo.strip().strip('/')

# Pega somente o nome
arquivo = basename(arquivo)

with request.open(url) as response, open(arquivo, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.read())

driver.quit()
```

### Sessões e cookies

OS exemplos anteriores são básicos, servem mais para entender como você pode tentar resolver, mas é importante notar que site usam cookies e as vezes os links só estão disponíveis através deles, pois o site por usar um *anti-crsf* (com cookie/sessão) ou sessão, o que impediria você de acessar o link via Python, no entanto é possivel contornar, o próprio Selenium oferece o método `driver.get_cookies()`, ele retorna os cookies do site atual e do *path* atual (se houverem cookies exclusivos setados para outros caminhos no mesmo domínio creio que este método não os retorne, ele é semelhante ao `document.cookie` do JavaScript no navegador), ao usar ele retornará um objeto, algo como (este exemplo retornou do site da google, omiti alguns cookies sensiveis):

```
[{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1569293037.639768, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '1P_JAR', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '2019-08-25-02'}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1571885037, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'OGPC', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '19013527-1:'}, {'domain': 'www.google.com', 'expiry': 1566787437, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'UULE', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '...'}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1582512236.772455, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'NID', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '...'}]
```

Então tendo o objeto que contém os cookies você agora deve passar os valores para uma das funções do `urllib` (ou de outra lib de sua preferencia, afinal em Python tem mais de uma lib, nativa ou não para o serviço).

Para resolver isto você pode usar:

```
from http.cookiejar import Cookie, CookieJar
```

E definir o "jarro de cookies" no urllib assim:

```
jar = CookieJar()

request_cookie = Cookie(0, cookie_name, cookie_value, port, port_specified, domain,
                            domain_specified, domain_initial_dot, path, path_specified,
                            secure, expires, discard, comment, comment_url, rest, rfc2109)

jar.set_cookie(request_cookie)

opener = request.build_opener(request.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
```

> Assim que possivel irei colocar um exemplo funcional